# package.json "homepage" does not appear on github repo

Tags: github, package.json

As I understand it, have a "homepage" entry in my package.json file should cause it to appear on the top of the repo. Ditto for "description". When I do this, the homepage url does not appear.

For example, Three.js has:

> "description": "JavaScript 3D library",
>
> "homepage": "http://threejs.org/",

.. resulting in:

[image]

My repo has:

> "description": "eXperimental modules for AgentScript, 2nd Edition",
>
> "homepage": "http://backspaces.github.io/asx/",

.. yet shows only the description:

[image]

No homepage url.  Maybe description too long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly add your website on GitHub.

[image: Edit button]

[image: Edit the website]

Comment: Yeah, I noticed and am using it now. Our current ecology is so broad it is a "Buffet" not an "Architecture". Loosely coupled, Tightly aligned.